# What's the actual type in this lambda function?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a code that combines 3 lambda functions:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename F, typename G, typename H>
    auto concat(F f, G g, H h) {
    return [=](auto... parameters) {
        return f( g( h( parameters... ) ) );
    };
}

int main() {
    auto func1 (
        [](int i) {
            return (i * 2);
        }
    );

    auto func2 (
        [](int i) {
            return (i % 2);
        }
    );

    auto combined (
        concat(func1, func2, greater<int>{})
    );

    cout << combined(3, 2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My question is: what is the actual type (F, G, H) in template? Is it a function pointer, or a function object, or something else? How can I illustrate its type in code?

Comment: In this case they are all function objects. But since a function object without any capture is equivalent to a function pointer they are more or less the same here.

Comment: @super A captureless lambda can be converted to a function pointer, but that doesn't make them equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every lambda expression has an unnamed unique class type, and the only way to refer to its type is to apply `decltype` to it.

In this particular instantiation of `concat`, the types are `decltype(func1)`, `decltype(func2)`, and `greater<int>`, respectively.
The result type is `decltype(concat(func1, func2, greater<int>{}))`.

Comment: plus one for `decltype` somehow I forgot that and now I dont want to steal it from this answer ;)

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo. Is there a way of printing out `decltype(func1)` and `greater<int>` in standard `cout`?

Comment: @dxfkgdkjfgbizldu you can make the compiler spit out an error message that mentions the type of the lambda, but don't expect something too meaningful. Eg https://godbolt.org/z/NbXRQr

Answer (score 4):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> The lambda expression is a prvalue expression of **unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate class type**, known as closure type, which is declared (for the purposes of ADL) in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the lambda expression.

In other words, each lambda expression has a unique unnamed type. `F` and `G`  are deduced as the type of the lambdas that you use to instantiate the template. It is not a function pointer.

For illustration you can consider that lambdas are syntactic sugar for functors. Ie the corresponding type for `func1` is something similar to

```
struct "no name" {
    auto operator()(int i) const {
        return (i * 2);
    }
);
```